# How to access an XML file after publishing a project?

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio

I can load my XML file as expected during debugging mode using the code as follows:

```
Dim strm As New FileStream(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(Application.StartupPath & "\QuestionList.xml"), FileMode.Open)
```

But after I published my project using ClickOnce Deployment, an error message is always prompting stating that:

Could not find the file:
'C:\Documents and Settings*username*\Local Settings\Apps\2.0\RANDOM CHARACTERS HERE\QuestionList.xml'

A File not found exception occurs.

My problem is similar with [this question here in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024485/how-do-i-access-an-xml-file-that-is-included-in-the-project), and tried the solutions proposed out there but with no luck, just like the original poster.

Why can't I access an XML file onced I **published** my project?

Comment: Removed C# tag. Let me know if this is a mistake.

Comment: Do you have the file in place?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Yes, in my Application folder, but does not appear in 'C:\Documents and Settings*username*\Local Settings\Apps\2.0\RANDOM CHARACTERS HERE\QuestionList.xml'

Comment: What is your application folder? When you deploy it as clickonce application your application folder will be in somewhat like Temp folder only

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Sorry I mean it is placed just as where my forms and other resources are. That's why I am calling `Application.StartupPath & "\QuestionList.xml"`. Should I place it somewhere else?

Comment: Why not add the xml in your click once project and copy the file in ApplicationPath ?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Hmm what do you mean by my "click once project"? Is it in the bin or debug folder. Sorry, I'm new  in this one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940025/adding-files-to-a-click-once-deployment this could help

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40402/discussion-between-arman-and-sriram-sakthivel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clickonce applications once deployed will be in `AppData\XYZ...BlahBlahBlah`. You get an error because your xml doesn't exist there. That is the path where you need your `QuestionList.xml`  to make it work.

So basically you need to deploy your xml when you deploy your binaries, Follow the instructions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940025/adding-files-to-a-click-once-deployment), It will guide you how to copy files to clickonce installation path.

Answer (score 0):

try using double slash:

```
"\\QuestionList.xml"
```

Comment: hmm 
also (in C#..) I would try something like)

    string x = Application.StartupPath & "\QuestionList.xml";

and use    @x    as parameter